# What is the difference between min and argmin in the context of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the indepdently distributed expenontial variables $T_1,T_2,T_3,...T_N$ and let $M=\min_{i=1,...,N} T_i$ and $i_s=arg min_{i=1,...,N} T_i$.

Now I understand the difference between min f(x) and argmin f(x) in the context of deterministic function, but in the context of random variables I'm lost as to the difference. Isn't the argument the variables themselves? So let's say that the outcome of $T_3$ is the smallest of the set, so that the outcome of $M$ is $T_3$, then isn't the outcome of $i_s$ also $T_3$?

Comment: No, the outcome of $i_s$ is literally $3$ and the outcome of $M$ is the value that $T_3$ takes.

Comment: aaaaaaah. I see. So argmin is the value of the i, for which $T_i$ was the smallest

please add this as a reply so I can accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the argmin should be thought of as "where" the minimum takes place. In this case, the outcome of $i_s$ is literally $3$, the index at which the minimum is attained, and the outcome of $M$ is the value that $T_3$ takes.